# Azure logic app SFTP Get File Content Using Path fails with bad gateway

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which previously was getting a .zip file from an FTP server. Now the server is changed to a new SFTP server and I'm trying to update the app in the azure web portal.
I'm using an SFTP connection with password. The app reads the file's metadata first and this task is working - it returns the file's timestamp and size.

Next task is "Get File Content Using Path" - targeting the same file. This task fails with error 502 - Bad Gateway: Failed to read file.

I have manually checked the file with WinSCP - the .zip file is fine, I can read or copy it.

Any ideas what this could be?

The weird part is the metadata working.
I've seen mentions of IP not being whitelisted causing this - but shouldn't metadata task fail in that case too?

Comment: Can you add screenshots of your workflow, in particular the "Get File Content Using Path" task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if your SFTP server has firewall and if you have set the SFTP server allow your logic app ip address to access the data.

You can find the ip address of your logic app on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#inbound-ip-addresses) and check if it is allowed to access your SFTP server.

Comment: Confirmed to be SFTP server issue, logic app works with another SFTP server tested on. No idea what the issue is though as I do not have access to the server to check/test.